# Does BlockingCollection re-try if its underlying collection is not empty but TryTake fails?

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

[BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) is a wrapper around [IProducerConsumerCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1). My understanding is that calling `BlockingCollection.Take` checks if there is an item available (using its own counter). Then it uses `TryTake` on its underlying collection to retrieve said item.

Now of course there has to actually exist an item in the underlying collection (and no external modification happening). But what happens if `TryTake` fails for some other reason, and the underlying collection returns false to `TryTake`? Does the wrapper just give up, or does it try to take the item again (supposedly succeeding next time)?

The ominous "other reason" could be an internal delay e.g. if the data structure is distributed.

Comment: PLEASE leave a comment what's wrong with the question. I honestly have no idea anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only thing you can definitely take for granted is what's written in the documentation. But you can just take a look at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,550):

```
public T Take()
{
    T item;

    if (!TryTake(out item, Timeout.Infinite, CancellationToken.None))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.BlockingCollection_CantTakeWhenDone));
    }

    return item;
}
```

In other words, the reason why `TryTake` returns `false` is irrelevant; `Take` will throw.

Comment: However, the TryTake in this answer refers to BlockingCollection internally, not to the underlying instance. So right now, this is not a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Joey's answer linked to the source code and gave the right result, but the problem is a little more nuanced.

`BC.Take` calls `BC.TryTake` (*not* on the underlying collection). `BC.TryTake` then waits for a semaphore. This semaphore is incremented when an item was added to the BC.

Then it calls `Underlying.TryTake` and [throws directly if that returns false](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,732). Abbreviated:

```
//If an item was successfully removed from the underlying collection.
removeSucceeded = m_collection.TryTake(out item);
if (!removeSucceeded) {
    // Check if the collection is empty which means that the collection was modified outside BlockingCollection
    throw new InvalidOperationException (SR.GetString(SR.BlockingCollection_Take_CollectionModified));
}
```

This is the only place where `Underlying.TryTake` is called in BC.

So `TryTake` is indeed never allowed to fail. However, it is guaranteed (by the current BC code) that `TryTake` is only called after a corresponding `TryAdd`. So the underlying data structure just needs to make sure that the operations of `TryTake` are never delayed beyond the end of operations of `TryAdd`, since BC will not attempt to `TryTake` while the `TryAdd` of the sole element is *still in progress*.